# Keyboard doesn't disappear on question search

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, android-app

If you defocus the search field without hitting "search", the keyboard refuses to disappear.

1. Go to a question list
2. Type in the search box
3. Click the sort options and choose a different one

You get search results with the keyboard still showing. If you click a result, the keyboard is still there. Make it stop!

[image: keyboard remaining open after field defocus]

Comment: Could you add in some freehand circles? I'm having difficulty figuring out what the screenshot is showing.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in version 0.1.60 coming out later tonight.